# Is there a way to check user password with Spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to check if password is correct for already logged user. Is there a way to do it with spring security, without manually getting password from database and so on?

Comment: define username and password in spring-servlet.xml and try

Comment: There is no more password after authentication, it is removed from the user for security reasons. So no there is no way. Why do you even need to check the password for an already authenticated user?

Comment: @M.Deinum For password changing logic. Old password + 2 times new password.

Comment: Check the stored password is your option. You will need to retrieve it again.